# Making wired connection

Tags: 14.04, connection, lan, wired

If I connect Windows 8 laptop to PC running Windows through lan cable, I see connected PC on my laptop.

If I try the same with Ubuntu - connecting laptop with Ubuntu to PC running Ubuntu, I don't see connected PC.

Is there some easy guide how to connect 2 computers running Ubuntu through lan cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because windows use Automatic Private IP Addressing (APIPA). What it does is when there's no DHCP to assign IP address automatically the windows machine assigns itself a random IP from the range of 169.254.0.1 through 169.254.255.254. 
So what you can do is when you connect your Ubuntu with cable you can manually assign a random IP address from the range of 169.254.0.1 through 169.254.255.254 and you'll have connection to the windows computer. You only need to watch out not to assign the same IP address the windows machine has assigned itself (you can check it running ipconfig in CMD).
I hope that helps!